# WPF ComboxIF statement

Tags: c#, wpf

I have a combobox in a WPF XAML window. I want to have an IF statement in my .cs where I can then assign a method to it when the user has that item selected.

Here is the XAML bit:

```
<ComboBox x:Name="comboBoxThickness" HorizontalAlignment="Left" 
Margin="469,380,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="155" IsEditable="True" 
MaxWidth="150" Text="Select Plate Thickness">
<ComboBoxItem x:Name="Combo8mm" Content="8mm" />
<ComboBoxItem x:Name="Combo12_5mm" Content="12.5mm" />
</ComboBox>
```

Here is the .cs part (with an attempt made):

```
    private void WeightCal()
    {
        if (Combo8mm.Selected){

        }
    }
```

Comment: UI elements such as ComboBoxes provide events you can subscribe to that signal selection changes. However, since you are using WPF, i would recommend to play to its strength an look into using MVVM design pattern - as your time and motivation permits, of course ;)  - and how to leverage data bindings than can let viewmodels both react to and do selection changes (yes, ComboBoxes also have bindable properties that provide - as well as allow to change - the currently selected element).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your question, I have added code snippet assuming that you wanted to do something on combo-box selected changed event.

**Case 1 :-**

I have done little modification to your xaml and code-behind.

1. Added a SelectedChanged event to combobox as below.

   ```
   <ComboBox x:Name="comboBoxThickness" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="155" IsEditable="True" 
                      MaxWidth="150" Text="Select Plate Thickness" SelectionChanged="comboBoxThickness_SelectionChanged">
               <ComboBoxItem x:Name="Combo8mm" Content="8mm" />
              <ComboBoxItem x:Name="Combo12_5mm" Content="12.5mm" />
   </ComboBox>
   ```
2. Then in the code behind in the event handler, you can check which Combobox item is selected like below,

   ```
   private void comboBoxThickness_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
   {
          var selectedItem = comboBoxThickness.SelectedItem as ComboBoxItem;
          if(selectedItem.Content.ToString() == "8mm")
           {
               // Write your logic here
           }
   }
   ```
3. You can multiple if..else conditions to check and do necessary actions in each if condition as per your requirements.

Note:- Even though the approach you have followed was not recommended. Always rely on MVVM which helps you in long run.

And in the above code I am just trying to compare the selected combo-box item content with string. Assuming it is always a string in your case. You have to check and test the code in your project.

**Case 2:-**

In case if you want to get the selected item in some method, you can directly use this below statement instead of checking that each combo-box item is selected or not which you have written in your code.

```
   var selectedItem = comboBoxThickness.SelectedItem as ComboBoxItem;
   if(selectedItem.Content.ToString() == "8mm")
    {
        // Write your logic here
    }
```

If there is something else that you are looking for, then let us know.